# Passing custom params to state resolve functions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to pass an optional param into a resolve function for a configured state?

So something like

```
resolve: {
    resA: getSomething(1),
    resB: getSomethingElse
}


function getSomething(num) {
    if(num===1) {
        //do something here
    }
    return something
}

function getSomethingElse() {
)
```

I am looking to reuse the resolve function on other states, but in certain cases I require different logic to be executed inside the function.

Can anyone offer some suggestions?

Thanks

**EDIT**

OK, so I am actually looking at passing in a custom param to a resolve function that is dependant on an earlier resolve function.

```
resolve: {
    resA: getSomething,
    resB: getSomethingElse(1)
}

function getSomething() {
    return something
}

function getSomethingElse(num, resA) {

)
```

In this example, the second resolve gets fired immediately as soon as the state is hit and doesn't wait until `resA` gets resolve, so I can console.log out the `num` param but `resA` is undefined at that point.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and you can reuse it across states, just make sure the functions you call are defined before you call resolve.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question further with a more specific scenario I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example:

```
resolve: {
  resA: getSomething,
  resB: getSomethingElse(1)
}
```

the values of resA and resB must be functions. It's the case for resA. For resB, it's the case only if `getSomethingElse(1)` returns a function. So getSomethingElse must look like

```
function getSomethingElse(value) {
    return function() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Let's suppose that `getSomething` returns 'hello'. And let's suppose you want the function returned by `getSomethingElse(1)` to use that value `hello`. You thus need to tell ui-router that the function referenced by `resB` needs the result of `resA`as argument:

```
function getSomethingElse(value) {
    return function(resA) { // the name of the argument MUST BE resA. This function will be injected 
        // ...
    }
}
```

And now you can thus use both value and resA in that function. For example, to do an http call depending on the value and on resA:

```
function getSomethingElse(value) {
    return function($http, resA) { 
        if (value === 0) {
            return $http.get('/zero').then(...);
        }
        else {
            return $http.get('/one/' + resA).then(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful technique to know!